# Partial calls to MPI_file_read_at_all in Fortran

Tags: optimization, io, fortran, mpi

I need to read a very big binary Fortran file in parallel with MPI. 
The problem is that the file is so big that each cores cannot even store #total_file_size/ncpu on memory. 
Therefore each cpu read sequentially part of the file.

I have the following pseudo code:

```
ir_start = start reading position for that cpu
ir_stop = end reading position for that cpu

CALL MPI_FILE_OPEN(world_comm,filint,MPI_MODE_RDONLY,MPI_INFO_NULL,fh,ierr)
size = size of the chuck to read
DO ir=ir_start, ir_stop
  offset = data_size * (ir -1)
  CALL MPI_FILE_READ_AT(fh, offset, data, size, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
ENDDO
```

This works well. 
However I was told that MPI_FILE_READ_AT_all (collective) would be much faster.

The problem is that if I use the collective version, then it only works if all the cores have the same number of elements (i.e. ir_stop-ir_start is the same). 
This does not always happens. 
Therefore for some number of cores, the code just hang as it is waiting for the last cpu that does not enter the final loop.

Is there a clever way to make this work with the MPI_FILE_READ_AT_ALL for an arbitrary number of cores ?

Comment: Have you tried reading zero bytes on some ranks ?

Comment: I just tried and it works. However the speed gain is disappointing :(. I get 19.84 sec with the collective _AT_ALL reading compared to 20.28 sec with the old _AT non collective reading.

Comment: Do you have a file system which supports the distribution of a single file across multiple disks and the parallel reading of the file by multiple processes simultaneously ?

Comment: I think so. The cluster has a IBM General Parallel File System(GPFS).